# How do I build Ionic cordova for android?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and I want to emulate Ionic in an Android platform rather than to run it in a browser. But I am stuck with this error during **"ionic cordova build android"** using VS CODE.

**Please find the following details:**

```
> cordova.cmd requirements android

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 18.0.1
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-33,android-30
Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle-7.4.2\bin\gradle.BAT
```

**Actual Error:**

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED                                                                            

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                               

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @5cb1c671

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
17 actionable tasks: 17 executed
Command failed with exit code 1: E:\Ionic\Projects\NirogalayaFoundation\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b E:\Ionic\Projects\NirogalayaFoundation\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You need jdk 8 or 11 not 18. Please go through https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#java-development-kit-jdk

Comment: Do I have to uninstall the current JDK Version and then install jdk 8 or 11?  And also I have to change the system variables JAVA_HOME accordingly. Right?

Comment: You generally can have multiple jdks in your system. You have to point to the right now in PATH and JAVA_HOME

Comment: Thanks a lot @SurajRao . It worked. I installed the lower version JDK from the link given by you. And then I updated my System Variables - JAVA_HOME and set the location of my JDK (just before the BIN folder) and also I have updated System PATH variable to point to the BIN folder of the JDK location. Just in case anyone stuck with this problem, after updating the JDK always check your JDK version in the Command Mode by writing **java -version**. It will show you the current version installed. But before that change the Environment Variables as mentioned above and you are good to go.